# How to enable "Create Visio Diagram" in a Custom list?

Tags: visio-services

It seems like the "Create Visio Diagram" button, located in the "Connect & Export" section under List ribbon, only works for Task list and Calendar list types. I am looking for a way to enable the button on a Custom list.

(Laura Rogers shows how to use the button in Task list here: http://www.sharepoint911.com/blogs/laura/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=62)

Once the button is enabled, I will need to map the list columns to objects in Visio. Is this done programatically (using Visio SDK) entirely?

Please let me know. Any help or direction will be greately appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I am moving this question to stackoverflow; it seems like there is more of a follwing there than here for visio and sharepoint questions.

Comment: Is it possible to have the same idea but used for Office Layout?

Comment: If I understand you question correctly, you are talking about adding a similar button to other Office applications?

Comment: You can refer to my question - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/visio-diagram-link-to-sharepoint-2007 - do let me know if I interpret your question & the link (Laura Rogers) wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every action is applicable to every list or library type within SharePoint and this might be one of those cases.  You could try to use one of those base lists types, get rid of the default contant type and add your own content type to the list and see if that nets the desired affect.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I believe there needs to be some kind of "wiring" between the list and the ribbon button itself - unless a particular set of content types automatically enables the button - in which case we're still bound by the a specific set of content types.