# Visio Diagram link to SharePoint 2007

Tags: list, sharepoint-designer, visio-services

May I know what are the steps to create a office layout inside Microsoft Visio Diagram, then link this Visio Diagram to SharePoint List, such that when my mouse hover at a particular location in the Visio Diagram, it display its corresponding information in the SharePoint List.

It should like something like the following (The picture is for SharePoint 2010 but I need the steps for SharePoint 2007):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

- Create a visio diagram using Maps and Floor Palns >> Floor Plan stencil.
- Once the map is created, go to the Data tab on visio and click ok Link Data to Shapes. Choose SharePoint List option.
- The data will show on the bottom of the diagram. Drag and drop each row of data that you want to be visible upon hovering the section of the diagram.
- Save the file as .vdw and upload it to a SharePoint document library.
- Create a Visio webpart and point it to the uploaded .vdw diagram.
- When the diagram loads on the webpart, make sure to Toggle the visibility of the shape information panel on the top right corner.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I have the following questions as follows: [1] Is the Visio apply for Visio 2007 or only for Visio 2010? (Currently have Visio 2007 and SharePoint 2007) [2] Where can I locate this Visio webpart in SharePoint 2007? (I search but could not find it in my SharePoint Sites) [3] Is the Visio a web-based when access at SharePoint or it will just open as a file that need to be open by Visio at the Client workstation?

Comment: Wilson, [1] The above steps are for Visio 2010 Professional - alternative ways: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa463345(office.12).aspx; http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=1CDBB7E7-6BD4-488F-91BD-7BD732DBF378&displaylang=en
 [2] MOSS 2007 does not have the Visio Web Access web part like SharePoint 2010 - alternative way: http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/martinisti/archive/2010/06/09/visio-drawing-in-sharepoint-2007.aspx, [3] If you have the visio webpart, or save the visio file in web drawing format, it does not require a client - it is browser renderable.